# Dynamic function assigning and calling through Object, Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, this

I assigned a click handler to a dynamically generated button. I am calling a callback inside the click handler function. Unfortunately, I am getting an error stating that

> "Callback function is not a function".

I am providing the basic code below.

HTML (Component 2) -

```html
<button *ngFor="let btn of content.buttons" type="button"
        (click)="btn.func()" class="{{btn.type}}">
    <span class="btn-text">{{btn.text}}</span>
</button>
```

TS (Component 2) -

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-popup',
})

@Input() content;
```

Code of the component from where I am passing the data -

HTML (Component 1) -

```
<app-popup [content]="popupContent"></app-popup>
```

TS (Component 1) -

```
this.popupContent = {
  "buttons":[{
        "text":"OK",
        "type":"btn-red",
        "func": this.someHandler
  }]
};

someCallbackFunction(){
  console.log('I am a callback function');
}

someHandler(){
  this.someCallbackFunction();
}
```

When I fire the event on button click, it throws this error-

> ERROR TypeError: this.someCallbackFunction is not a function

I also tried setting the handler like

```
(click)="btn[func]()"
```

but unfortunately it didn't work for me.

Please suggest a solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling the function through a fat arrow function, it should have the correct `this` context that way. Just change how you define it.

```
"buttons":[{
     "text":"OK",
     "type":"btn-red",
     "func": () => { this.someHandler(); }
}];
```

[Read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) about why context is being lost and the function not being found.

Comment: Thanks @dince12, it worked. Thanks again for clarifying :)

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Modify `"func": this.someHandler` to `"func" :() => this.someHandler()`

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nzevtj?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

```
buttons =[{
    "text":"OK",
    "type":"btn-red",
    "func" :() => this.someHandler()
}]
```

Comment: Thanks, @Adrita :). Helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

**Please Use @Output for this**

**At popup component.ts (child component);
Html**

```
<button *ngFor="let btn of content.buttons" type="button" (click)="btnClicked()" class="{{btn.type}}">
<span class="btn-text">{{btn.text}}</span>
</button>
```

**Ts (child component)**

```
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Output() onBtnClicked = new EventEmitter<any>();

btnClicked(){
 this.onBtnClicked.emit(1);
}
```

**At Parent Component
Html (Parent Component)**

```
<app-popup [content]="popupContent" (onBtnClicked)="onBtnClicked($event)"></app-popup>
```

**Ts (Parent Component)**

```
onBtnClicked(event){

}
```